# How to get the parentNode of a DOMText?

Tags: php, dom, domdocument, libxml2

I am using [`DOMText`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domtext.php), but this is a generic `DOMDocument` question: if a variable `$X` is a instance of `DOMText`, how can I get its parent node?

The manual does not define `DOMText::$parentNode` as a property.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do a little investigative work sometimes to work out what properties a class has:

```
DOMText extends DOMCharacterData {
DOMCharacterData extends DOMNode {

// DOMNode has
public readonly DOMNode $parentNode ;
```

So `DOMText` has the `$parentNode` property, as do all classes that extend `DOMNode`, directly or indirectly.

Only the properties defined in a particular class are listed in the manual, not those inherited from ancestors.

Comment: Ops, my bug was other problem (yes, `$X->parentNode` works)... Well, thanks a lot!  Your answer will help me (and others) to read and understand the guides.